# Is there a way to force uncle blocks generation in a testnet?

Tags: testnets, testing, blocks, uncle-blocks

In a local testnet, what could be done to force uncle blocks generation? I'm mining with multiple geth instances (different accounts) on a common CPU and very low difficulty genesis block.

Answer (score 1):

I guess not, but what you can do is to have two different computers mining at the same time (while the difficulty is still low), so with some probability there will be uncle blocks.